# Post on Google+ Stream using Google+ API

Tags: google-plus

Any one have idea about how to post on our Google+ Stream using Google+ API? I need to post on the stream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post in google plus wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is still no "public" officially supported way to post on a Google+ stream using an API. (You can post using the +1 or Share buttons, and some people have used unofficial APIs or leveraged the SMS posting methods, but this isn't what you're looking for.)

For details on what you can currently do with the limited API you can look at https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: is this still valid ?

Comment: Primarily yes. Is there a reason you believe it isn't? (There are now some ways to do it if you're posting in an apps domain to other users in that same domain. But this is a very limited case. All of it is documented at that URL still.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an unofficial Google+ API written in js. https://github.com/mohamedmansour/google-plus-extension-jsapi

Comment: In "Issues" section it stated that this API doesn't work anymore. Please confirm it (I haven't test it).