# Posting to Google+ Stream

Tags: stream, google-plus, private, posting

Since Google+'s API only allows for public reading, has anyone figured out how to post to a Google+ stream or do private reading another way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on Google+ Stream using Google+ API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880021/post-on-google-stream-using-google-api)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot programmatically writing to a user's stream or reading private stream data. You can programmatically [write app activities](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/) to a user's profile.