# What is the end point URL to post the status in google plus?

Tags: salesforce, google-plus, apex-code

Am trying to post the status from salesforce app to google plus, so i need the endpoint URL for this process.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on Google+ Stream using Google+ API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880021/post-on-google-stream-using-google-api)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot programmatically or automatically post to a user's Google+ Stream with the [Google+ v1 API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/). If you are a Google Apps customer with your own Apps domain, you can use the [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) to [make automatic posts](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating), but these are restricted to users within that domain and only other users within the domain can see those posts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot publish to a user's Google+ profile automatically, but you can use the JavaScript API to add the functionality to your application. The Share button is a good way of doing this, but required 1-2 clicks from the user to actually share to their profile.

This [tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2013/10/02/google-api-sharing-an-interactive-post/) has some code you can use to create a Share button with custom content.