# How to Post on my google+ timeline using Oauth

Tags: google-plus, google-oauth

Is it possible to post something, from external Web-Application using Oauth.

For example 
  url: users/me/post?text=.......&token=received_token_from_google_oauth.

Comment: Yes, but a pain in the dark side. Read the OAuth2 doc, get the key from google(register your app, check the https://appengine.google.com ). You may do some test from python, with OAuth2 installed.

Comment: I already have my oauth setup :), The question is, how to post something on uses's timeline(wall) using it. What is the url, params, ect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on Google+ Stream using Google+ API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880021/post-on-google-stream-using-google-api)

Answer (score 3):

The Google+ APIs do not give you write access to a user's stream.