# Google Plus sharing using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-plus, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to share some data on google plus from my Website. Facebook and twitter is completed using NodeJS (Using npm twit and fb). in FB

```
 var FB = require('fb'); 
 FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { message: "something"}, function (result) {
 }
```

and in twitter

```
 var Twit = require('twit');
 T.post('statuses/update', { status: "something" }, function(err, data, response) {}
```

But I am stuck with Google Plus. I dont know how to do it by using NodeJS. Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/activities#resource

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post on Google+ Stream using Google+ API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880021/post-on-google-stream-using-google-api)

Comment: I checked all those things. But I have no Idea how to do it with NodeJS

Comment: Can i achieve it by using front end instead of back end technology