# how to post on google plus pages through api?

Tags: php, google-plus

how to post on Google+ pages through API using php

while searching for Google+ API got Google page API
( https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup ) which allows user to post on Google+ pages 
but to white list this API need to apply for Google+ page API 
i am not getting any documentation for Google+ page API (how to post on pages)

Answer (score 7):

Currently, there is no publicly available API to post to Google+. You found the signup form to request access to the API. If granted, Google will provide you with API information.

Comment: Ok, but how do all those news sites like gizmodo publish their posts automatically to their google page?

Comment: There is a limited access API which can provide access. HootSuite, for example, allows you to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this link. Google has released Page API but limited to certain companies and selection criteria seems to be very tough.

[Google + Pages API - Partner Application Form](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup)

Answer (score 2):

We have tried to found another ways to post on Google+ but don't got any solution because Google+ is providing higher securty for writing permission.

Google+ default providing permission which is read permission and using our regular google account we can easily do it but we want to post on Google+ so we'll need google permission and for permission we'll need to create google domain account.

**Please check this note which is google said:**

Important: The access.domainRestricted property must be set to true for posts using the Google+ Domains API. Posts in Google+ are private by default so you must also specify the access.items property to choose the audience within the domain that is authorized to view the post.

**And grant permissions which is google also said:**

Required - Grants permission for the app to create posts or comments on behalf of a user. The Google+ Domains API only allows creation of restricted posts, and only allows comments to be added to restricted posts.

> **You can check these bellows links :**

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2705802 https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert#auth

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/scopes

https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert

Comment: You may read my comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-wall/40173486#40173486