# PHP - Post article on my google plus page stream

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

Is it possible to post something on **my** google plus business page stream?

I've found some examples on how to read the data from google plus, but nothing about adding to the inside.

It's to publish new articles from my page to g+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible, yes.  But you first have to apply for access to the Google+Pages API using their Partner Application Form: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup

As it says on the form: "Access to this API is available through a whitelist, and access is granted to partners on a company by company basis dependent on fit with this API."

Also, here's another related question on StackOverflow that might help:
[how to post on google plus pages through api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272963/how-to-post-on-google-plus-pages-through-api)

If you're using Wordpress it looks like it's possible using this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/