# Is that now possible to post your own Google+ page via application?

Tags: c#, google-plus

Is that now possible to post your own Google+ page via application?

Like in twitter and facebook

Facebook does have its own SDK at NuGet which is awesome

For twitter i use LinqToTwitter

If possible are there any framework, 3rd party library for c#?

Thank you very much

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to post on google plus pages through api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14272963/how-to-post-on-google-plus-pages-through-api)

Comment: @abraham yes however since 2 years passed i thought maybe now google allows :D

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Kindly guide me how?Or send link.