# Is there any way to share on google plus stream, without entering to share dialog ..?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-api, google-plus, google-play-services

Is there any way to share a public post on google plus stream without entering to share dialog if so please help on this.

thanks in regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write app activities: https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities which will go to the user's activity log and Google will decide when to surface them to users.

Otherwise there is currently no way for you to write to the user's stream without the use of a share dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Too low of a reputation to comment, but check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7570416/2659245)

Where it states

> **UPDATE 3**: Google just announced [Google+ History](https://developers.google.com/+/history/). You can use it to write "moments" (which are private by default) but can then be
>   made public by sharing them directly to your stream and/or your
>   profile. One of the moment types is [`CommentActivity`](https://developers.google.com/+/history/api/moments#commentactivity).