# Does google plus api allows posting status?

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone, google-plus

I want to make an app for windows phone 8 to post status on Google plus with user signing in only once and without any Google's share button so that I can schedule the status update.
I tried googling but some old posts say that it cant be done while some point that some 3rd party apis can do it however I cant locate any reliable api.

**Is this thing possible to do now or still hard luck??**

**I know this thread [How to post in Google+ wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall?rq=1)
But it is 2 years old , I want to know if there is an update.**

Thanks.

Comment: Downvotes!!! What is wrong with people???

Comment: I hadn't downvoted, but they may have taken issue with your last sentence. To me, "point me to a reliable source to work on" sounds like asking to "recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource", which is off-topic for Stack Overflow. With that part removed, the question seemingly boils down to a yes/no question ("Is it possible?")

Comment: k removed that line . I didn't know that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply NO. I was also searching for the same earlier in summer & all in vain.