# Google plus stream posting

Tags: api, google-plus

How can we make a post to user stream in Google plus using API
Is there any PHP library we can use to post to stream/pages of Google plus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post in google plus wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The Google+ API does not support posting:

> **Note:** The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.

— https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data.