# How to update post on Google+ from my android app?

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to update post  like  message,my location from my android app to Google+ wall/stream whatever it is.I already registered my app on Google console and turn On Google+ API,also am able to get data from Google+ like profile,friend circle.

I don't know how to update post on Google+ ?

Is there any example or tutorial.....

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating

Comment: Note that the link from @OwenCao is only relevant if your post id done through a Google Apps Domain, and not for accounts in general.

Comment: @Prisoner you are right. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall), the Google+ API is currently limited to read-only access,so you will not be able to update or post any information anywhere through the API.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion ,i try to implement according to your suggestions.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no general API to let you write or edit Google+ posts that appear directly on the stream. The general philosophy behind the Google+ API is that anything posted must be done with an explicit user action. So while you can prompt the user to post from your app, the user must actually post it themselves.

Similarly, while you can create a app activity that will post on the user's profile without explicit user action, the user still has to take actions to make that visible. App activities are only visible to a limited group, and are not posted directly to the user's stream. To place it on the stream, the owner must explicitly share it. (App activities are meant for event-like actions, such as watching a movie or checking in at a location.)

Accounts that are part of a Google App Domain (ie - not gmail accounts) have this lifted slightly. Applications can automatically create a post with visibility limited to other members of the organization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and suggestion but am just confused in Google+ ,that how the user to share explicitly and about the visibility of post...Is there is any example so that i understand well,how to implement that\