# Post to Google+ streams using the API

Tags: api, post, stream, google-plus

As the topic alludes to, I'm trying to use the Google+ Developer API to post to user streams using OAuth. I've spent the day researching the issue, and it simply doesn't look like it's something that's supported. Am I overlooking something here, or have they decided not to allow that functionality?

Facebook's API makes this fairly straitforward with their Graph API, but it doesn't look like Google has implemented a way for a user to authorize a third-party to post on their behalf (or to post to Google+ through that third-party).

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7570416/3563847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - there is no way to authorize a third party to post. There is an open feature request for this - you can star it to track it: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41

Comment: I feared so. Thanks for the clarification, Ian.