# Share some Text and image on Google plus stream

Tags: c#, facebook, google-plus, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to share text and image on my Google plus stream. This text and image would be set by me.

I have do a lot of Research on this i have founded that Google plus API is read only then what did the moment insert do in G+ API ...??

Is there any way if i can sync the text from my Facebook or twitter account.
I have make this application in C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post in google plus wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)

Comment: what did the moment insert do in G+ API ...??

Comment: [Managing app activities in Google](https://developers.google.com/+/web/app-activities/)

Comment: Thanks

Is there any way to post on google plus page instead of stream.
Please let me know the steps for that, do we need to take approval from google 

plz check the link https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup

Comment: The Pages API is how you post to a Page and that is the form to sign up for access to the Pages API.