# How to Dynamically post on Google plus wall?

Tags: php, google-plus

I have code for post dynamically content on Google plus wall using javascript but i want to post using PHP.

This is Java script code :

```
function gRenderShare() {
    $('#share-button').show();
    var options = {
        contenturl: $('#link-url').val(),
        clientid: '*clientid*.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        prefilltext: $('#prefill-text').val(),       
        recipients: (gShareRecipient ? gShareRecipient.toString() : null),
        calltoactionlabel: ($('#call-to-action').val() ? $('#call-to-action').val() : null),
        calltoactionurl: $('#target-url').val(),
        onshare: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            alert(response);
        }
    };
    // Call the render method when appropriate within your app to display the button.
    gapi.interactivepost.render('share-button', options);        
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a forum or code writing service, so you need to have a go at writing some code, and show us exactly where you're getting stuck. Check out the [help] for tips on how to get the most out of this site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post in google plus wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)