# Unclean code behind JetPack's ability to post to your Google+ pages

Tags: wordpress, api, google-plus

As far as I know, you cannot use the Google+ API to post to your Google+ Pages, only to your profile.

So, the question is, how can [JetPack](http://jetpack.me/support/publicize/google/) post to your Google+ Pages on the wall(stream)?

How is that possible? Do they have some exception from Google?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post in google plus wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)

Comment: You cant post to a wall or a page using the Google+ API.  If that does work which I doubt it. They probably have some manual thing you will need to click on to post it or they have hacked it somehow.

Comment: I read though their documentation I think they are posting to moments.   Moments aren't the same as posting to a wall as its posted to the application.  I don't believe they show up publicly on the G+ website by I am be wrong by the way they are telling you to set things public.    It still wont post to your personal page.

Comment: It's posting to my pages. I use it on my website. DO they have some special agreement with Google?

Comment: BTW if your update is true then its off topic for Stackoverflow your question will be closed we don't do agreements.  we do codeing issues.

Comment: I removed your "update" from the question because it should have just been a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These few companies were granted special priviledges from Google. Read more here:
http://mashable.com/2011/11/15/google-plus-pages-third-party-apps/

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API to post to a Google+ Profile or Page.

There is, however, a [limited access API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/pages-signup) which allows a small number of companies to let its users post to a Google+ Page (but not a Profile).

I don't know if JetPack is using this API directly, or if it is working through a company that does have access to the API.

Comment: Author says its showing up on his profile not his page.

Comment: That is for Google Apps Domains only and doesn't allow public posting, just to other members of the domain.

Comment: I have found out why it works. They were granted the special access by Google http://mashable.com/2011/11/15/google-plus-pages-third-party-apps/