# Which api to use for publicly to post to google+?

Tags: rest, google-plus

I want to post only image, text, link to google plus through api but it will be for public people like hootsuite.com have ?

Comment: php library will be more good if there is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post in google plus wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)